PyAudio recording comes out empty
I am trying to see if I can get PyAudio to record from my USB microphone on my Kubuntu computer. When I run this script, it does create a file, but the file contains no audio. Not even background white noise. I can confirm that my microphone works in the audio device settings and in OBS. The first print statement does display the correct device name. I am using the following code:
import pyaudio
import wave

FRAMES_PER_BUFFER = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 48000
RECORD_SECONDS = 2
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "voice.wav"

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
                input_device_index=2)

print("recording from device " + str(audio.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, 2).get('name')))

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / FRAMES_PER_BUFFER * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(FRAMES_PER_BUFFER)
    frames.append(data)

print("done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()

It creates the following output:
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:877:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
recording from device USB Audio Device: - (hw:1,0)
done recording

I tried running the script with sudo, but it didn't seem to change anything. I changed some PulseAudio settings to make it ignore my USB microphone because at first the script wasn't detecting the microphone at all. It recognizes the microphone now, but it's still creating empty audio files.

Opened the audio file in a different app and the audio does work. Visual Studio Code just doesn't want to play the audio file for some reason.
